# In node.js how would I follow the Principle of Least Privilege?

Tags: node.js, security

*Imagine* a web application that performs two main functions:

1. Serves data from a file that requires **higher** privileges to read from
2. Serves data from a file that requires **lower** privileges to read from

**My Assumption:** To allow both files to be read from, I would need to run node using an account that could read both files.

If node is running under an account that can access both files, then a user who should not be able to read any file that requires higher privileges could potentially read those files due to a security flaw in the web application's code.  This would lead to disastrous consequences *in my imaginary web application world*.

Ideally the node process could run using a minimal set of rights and then temporarily escalate those rights before accessing a system resource.

**Questions:** Can node temporarily escalate privileges?  Or is there a better way?

If not, I'm considering running two different servers (one with higher privileges and one with lower) and then putting them both behind a proxy server that authenticates/authorizes before forwarding the request.

Thanks.

Comment: I think your bigger concern is having security flaws. This would not be an issue if you had no security flaws in your code.

Comment: Ah yes, now if only I could prove that my software had no security flaws.  ;)  http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ProofOfCorrectness

Comment: if you implement that load balancer infront of two different elevated node processes you need to proof the load balancer has no flaws ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky case indeed. In the end file permissions are a sort of meta-data. Instead of directly accessing the files, my recommendation would be to have some layer between the files in the form of a database table, or anything that could map the type of user to the file, and stream the file to the user if it exists.

That would mean that the so called web application couldn't just circumvent the file system permissions as easy. You could even set it up so that said files did not have server readable permissions, and instead were only readable by the in between layer. All it could do is make a call, and see if the user with given permissions could access the files. This lets you also share between multiple web applications should you choose. Also because of the very specific nature of what the in between layer does, you can enforce a very restricted set of calls.

Now, if a lower privileged user somehow gains access to a higher privileged user's account, they'll be able to see the file, and there's no way to really get around that short of locking the user's account. However that's part of the development process.

Answer (score 0):

No, I doubt node.js-out of the box-could guarantee least privilege.

It is conceivable that, should node.js be run as root, it could twiddle its operating system privileges via system calls to permit or limit access to certain resources, but then again running as root would defeat the original goal.

One possible solution might be running three instances of node, a proxy (with no special permissions) to direct calls to one or the other two servers run at different privilege levels. (Heh, as you already mention. I really need to read to the end of posts before leaping into the fray!)